# SHGetFolderPath returns garbage string in distribute version

Tags: c++, windows, string, desktop

```
    char desktopPath[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT r = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 0, desktopPath);
    if (r != S_OK) {
        throw XArch(new XArchEvalWindows());
    }
    m_desktopPath = CString(desktopPath);
```

It is so weird. This piece of code works in VS2010 under both the release and debug modes. After I distribute it and run the application, I would get an error saying "The system cannot find the file specified". The more strange thing is my colleague runs the same application on his machine and it works.

In MSDN it says SHGetFolderPath is deprecated, so I tried to use SHGetKnownFolderPath. It is the same situation.

```
    PWSTR desktopPathW = 0;

    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &desktopPathW);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        throw XArch(new XArchEvalWindows());
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(static_cast<void*>(desktopPathW));
```

Any idea about what is going on? Or how am I suppose to debug this?

Thanks in advance.
Jerry

Comment: Not related to this, but you *do* free the memory you allocate? And why allocate it dynamically, just make an array and don't worry about it instead.

Comment: Yes I deallocated the memory. I was using stack mmemory and it is the same so I changed it to heap just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments explicitly state that `S_OK` is the only success result, and the error codes *include* `S_FALSE`, `E_FAIL` and `E_INVALIDARG`. You incorrectly assume that these 3 are the only error codes.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful. Now I got an error saying"The system cannot find the file specified." But why is the program working in release and debug modes in VS2010, but not working after distribute. :(

Comment: @Jerry: You probably want to strip your program down to just a `main` with this one function call. It most likely is something not shown here. Impersonation perhaps?